# Error in SQlite tablequery in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a new android developer and am using SQlite for first time. I have a NullPointerException while creating Table and tried a lot to sort out the answer but was not able to. Am thanking in advance for your valuable time and help. Please find the code below:

```
 package com.example.kannan.football_manager;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    /**
     * Created by kannan on 25/1/16.
     */
    public class Admin_Database_Operations extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        public static final String ADMIN_DB="admin_info";
        public static final String ADMIN_TB="abmin_table";
        public static final String ADMIN_NAME="admin_name";
        public static final String ADMIN_PASS="admin_pass";
        public static  final String COLUMN_ID="column_id";

        public  static final  int database_version=1;

        //creating database

        public Admin_Database_Operations(Context c)
        {
            super(c, ADMIN_DB,null,database_version);
            Log.d("database creation","database created");
        }




        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqls) {

            String CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                    ADMIN_TB + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + ADMIN_NAME
                    + " TEXT," + ADMIN_PASS + " TEXT" + ")";

            sqls.execSQL(CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);


            Log.d("Database Operation","TABLE CREATED IN DATABASE");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        }

         public SQLiteDatabase sq;
        public void putInformation(Admin_Database_Operations ado,String name,String pass)
        {

            sq=ado.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

            cv.put(ADMIN_NAME,name);
            cv.put(ADMIN_PASS,pass);

            sq.insert(ADMIN_TB,null,cv);
            sq.close();

        }
    }



  package com.example.kannan.football_manager;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public Button btn_Admin;
        public  Button btn_Cancel;
        public Button btn_Login;
        public Button btn_cngepsw;

        public EditText edttxt_name;
        public EditText edttxt_pass;

        public SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
        public Context ctx;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
            //Declaring Nodes

          btn_Admin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Admin);
            btn_Cancel=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Cancel);
            btn_Login=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Login);
            btn_cngepsw=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_cngepsw);

            edttxt_name=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt_name);
            edttxt_pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edttxt_pass);


            btn_Login.setOnClickListener(
                    new Button.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            String name="kannan";
                            String pass="pass";
                            Admin_Database_Operations ado=new Admin_Database_Operations(ctx);

                            ado.onCreate(sqldb);

                            ado.putInformation(ado, name, pass);

                            Log.d("Database operation", "INSERT ONE RAW");


                        }

                    }

            );


            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_login, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

//Error

```
01-30 17:06:15.253 3677-3677/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.kannan.football_manager, PID: 3677
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.kannan.football_manager.Admin_Database_Operations.onCreate(Admin_Database_Operations.java:40)
                                                     at com.example.kannan.football_manager.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:54)
                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not call onCreate() method, and check below code 
[How to insert data into a SQLite database in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895)